# Packaging content files correctly

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, nuget-package, nuspec, nuget-spec

Let there be 3 projects.

*Project #1* is a nuget package consumed by *Project #2*.

*Project #2* is a nuget package consumed by *Project #3*. It needs to perform codegen using codegen utilities provided by *Project #1*.

*Project #3* is an application.

**Project #1**

1. These are the content files that should appear in the solution explorer tree of *Project #2*. They should NOT appear in the solution explorer tree of *Project #1* or *Project #3*
2. My clumsy attempt at packing the content files into the nuget package's `/contentFiles` folder. **How can I write this better to achieve goals and eliminate issues?**
3. Oops. The content files wrongly appear here. **How do I stop that happening?**
4. Library code that needs to get packaged into a dll. It should be consumed by *Project #2* and *Project #3*

[image]

**Project #2**

1. Correctly referencing *Project #1*
2. Content files are appearing correctly and the custom tool runs correctly to perform codegen.
3. I don't want the content files to appear in *Project #3*, so I've clumsily tried to stop them with this. **How can I make this better (preferably automatic)?** I can't use `<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>` because the .dll file needs to get passed through to *Project #3*.
4. Visual Studio added that when I added installed the package for *Project #1*. Interesting. **What is it?**

[image]

**Project #3**

1. References *Project #2* with PackageReference (2)
2. How did this content file get here!! **How do I get rid of it?** It's causing a compile error also :(

[image]